# How to skip typing " while typing code in VSCode

Tags: go

Having to reach right arrow key after typing (") after a string etc on the keyboard when I'm typing the code is a pain in the _ for me. Can anyone show a trick to skip the double quote in the following line as marked? Is any keyboard shortcut other than the right arrow key on the keyboard? It's very annoying.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: just type the quote as if it weren't already there

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps use `fillstruct` to flesh out the struct?

Reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go

Comment: This question isn't about filling a struct, it's about skipping past the symbols that VSCode automatically inserts, once you have finished typing in what goes between them.